# Output empty with exec command

Tags: php, exec

I'm trying to launch a PHP file with exec which doesn't work.
Here is the code :

```
$output =NULL; 
exec("php /path/server/public/php/reports/templates/1.php > /dev/null &", $output);
echo "<pre>" . var_export($output, TRUE) . "</pre>\\n";
```

The website is hosted on OVH.
$output is empty and exec is not launched. If anybody as an idea of what's wrong.. Thank you very much.

Comment: Anything in the PHP error logs?

Comment: you are redirecting the output to /dev/null

Comment: isn't there a  built in function for executing external php code?

Comment: in javascript you have eval()

Comment: I guess when using the `&` to fork the other PHP-Script to background, after finishing the calling PHP-File, the exec()'d Process might recieve a SIGHUP, therefore terminating before finishing.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
passthru("php /path/server/public/php/reports/templates/1.php > /dev/null &", $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you pointing to /dev/null? This will redirect the output away from your session.
The & might also not be useful in this case as exec will need to wait for your second script to finish in order to print output.

```
exec("/path/to/script.php", $output);
```

Should work as long as:

- The permissions are set correctly (folders and the script executable)
- Your host has allowed the use of exec